# git filter-branch: filter directories by excluding, not including?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Suppose I have this structure in repo:

```
repo/
  dir1/
  dir2/
  dir3/
  dir4/
  dir5/
  ...
```

Now I want to keep all directories, except `dir1` and `dir2`.

I can use this command to keep specified directories.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch -- . && git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- dir3 dir4 dir5 ... dirN' --prune-empty -- --all
```

Now if I have many directories, it would be simpler to exclude directories I don't need instead of specifying the ones I need. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `index-filter` to specifically remove the *unwanted* paths, and not do anything to any of the others, i.e., the `--index-filter` part becomes:

```
--index-filter 'git rm --cached -qr --ignore-unmatch dir1 dir2'
```

The index-filter you use now consists of two separate commands joined by `&&`.  These commands are, in text form:

- Remove everything.  (The `--ignore-unmatch` is pointless here since you use `.` to specify "everything that exists", and "everything that exists" obviously exists.)
- Then, put back `dir3`, `dir4`, etc., from the current commit.

Since you just want to remove (recursively) "everything in `dir1`" and "everything in `dir2`", specify those.  Keep the `--ignore-unmatch` if there may be commits in which no `dir1` and/or `dir2` files exist.  After removing what you want gone, you don't need to put anything back: the index—the temporary index that `git filter-branch` uses to achieve the filtering (see below)—now has the correct set of files in it.

#### Sidebar: what is this index anyway?

When you make new commits, Git doesn't actually use the files in your work-tree.  They're not important here.

Git has, instead, a thing—implemented mainly as a file named `.git/index`, really—that Git calls, variously, *the index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  This index holds a copy of every file taken *out of* the *current* commit, initially.  You can then use `git add` or `git rm` to update the files that are in the index, or take files completely out of the index.

You can think of the index as the *proposed next commit*.  When you run `git commit`, Git packages up the files that are in the index *at that point* and freezes them into a new, permanent,<sup>1</sup> read-only commit.  The files you see and work with, in your work-tree, are only there for *you*, not really for Git.  That's why, whenever you modify a work-tree file and want the change to go into the next commit, you have to `git add` all the time: `git add` tells Git *take the work-tree copy and use it to overwrite the index copy so that the **next** commit will have this version.*

When you use `git filter-branch`, you have a bunch of options.  The very slowest one, `--tree-filter`, takes each commit, copies it into a temporary index—because Git always needs an index for this stuff, even if it's not the regular main one—and then extract all the files from that temporary index into a temporary tree.  You can then modify the files in the temporary tree, using your `--tree-filter` code.  Git then re-reads the temporary tree, builds a new (but still temporary) index from that, and uses that to make a new commit.

All of this copying is *very* slow.  So filter-branch gives you `--index-filter`: this time, Git copies the commit to a temporary index, then lets you modify the temporary index directly.  The `git rm --cached` command modifies the index—or in this case, the temporary index instead—by removing files from it.  Then filter-branch makes a new commit from the temporary index.  This skips the slowest parts of `--tree-filter`.

You still wind up copying every commit in the repository to some new-and-improved one, but by doing it only in the temporary index that filter-branch provides, it goes a lot faster.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits are really only *semi-permanent*.  They last as long as Git can find them.  For much more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  When you use filter-branch, you copy some commit(s) to some new-and-improved ones, and have your Git try to forget the originals.  Eventually, your Git probably does forget them.

Comment: But it looks like your suggested command just removes files. And it shows in changes that files will be removed. Then suggests to stage that change. Which basically looks the same as I would just removed files manually and committed the change. How different is this command? I don't want to see a commit that  those directories were removed.
With my original command, it filters out those directories as if those changes never existed. Thats the way I want it to be filtered out.

Comment: My bad. I read your answer incorrectly. I thought that was the whole command you suggested. Didn't notice that it was specifically what to use for `index-filter`